# Django updating value in a loop

Tags: python, django

Please keep in mind, that I just started learning Django and MySQL.

I created a script that can read my transactions from my bank statements and added them to a MySQL table which contains the following fields: id,amount,creditordebit,bookingdate ,partner ,category

I'm trying to create an interactive site to loop over the newly added data and update the category field based on the transaction type/partner.

I want to loop over them one by one and categorize them using forms.ChoiceField.

So far I have created the forms.py and the forms.ChoiceField and choices list, but I am having trouble creating a view and template for this.

I have tried to use the QuerySet iterate() but I could not get the next item by id, it jumped straight to the last id.

Is this even possible with Django only or do I need to also include some JavaScript?

Thanks!

Edit:
A rough idea about what it would look like:
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y7f4.png)

Comment: What do you want the user to see?  Are you hoping to present a table?  Perhaps you should show us a sketch of what you're after.

Comment: Dear Tim, I have added a simple sketch, I hope you can give me some pointers on what to research. I think the database also needs a boolean to check if it was categorized yet or not. Thank you!

Comment: You can do them one at a time, but you will have to have an `<input type=hidden>` field to tell you what the next ID should be.  Right?  Your `<form>` will send back the `<select>` field with the chosen category, plus the id of the record you're changing, and the id of the next field to show.  Have you written that HTML yet?